# Question about Azure AD + Intune Licensing?

Tags: azure, intune

I am trying to understand the need to assign users Enterprise Mobility + E3 licenses in order to utilize Azure AD + Intune.

We have 14 users who will be moving up to Azure AD, but they need nothing more than the ability to log in and perform their daily tasks. All infrastructure will be joined by the Domain Admin and will be assuming the role of Enrollment admin. Is it possible to just have the Domain/Enrollment Admin licensed with EM+E5?

I've set up a small environment and everything worked fine with only having the Domain Admin set up to Enroll.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because billing\pricing questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: This is not a billing/pricing question.

Comment: yeah, its licensing, no real difference. `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.`

Comment: yes this is possible